# Russell's paradox as understood by current set theorists

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, type-theory

Many mathematicians like to think of the set of natural numbers as existing as a completed object.  But it is difficult to make set theory as concrete, because  Russell's paradox, in conjunction with some type of separation principle, tells us that arbitrary "collections" cannot be collected into a completed object.  I view this as telling us that the metaphysical idea of "collection" has some natural limitations that we might not have realized, *a priori*.

Now, in terms of the formal mathematics of collections---known as set theory---there seem to be two standard fixes to address the paradox.

**Class and set distinction**  First is the idea of creating a new level of collection called "proper classes".  In some set theories like ZFC, classes are an informal notion referring to the formulas of the language.  Some mathematicians still view those classes as referring to meta-collections in the metatheory.  They even use set-builder notation to refer to them.  In other versions of set theory, like NBG or KM, classes are also formal objects.  Sometimes they are of a different type than sets, and sometimes sets are classes with extra properties.

Those theories with classes can often be reinterpreted inside the theories without classes, and vice versa.  Thus, it seems that Russell's paradox does not prescribe the existence, Platonically speaking, of two distinct types of collections---the set and the proper class.  Yet this language has also become very useful to mathematicians.  My question is somewhat philosophical in nature.  Do modern set theories view proper classes as a necessary, true concept?  Do they favor the view that proper classes are only informal, or are they formal?

I have a follow up question, for those set theorists that believe a "true Platonic set theory" exists.  How do you view that completed set theory in light of Russell's paradox?  It seems that a "true set theory" couldn't be like a collection itself (hence not like a set, nor like a proper class even).  In particular, "true Platonic set theory" would be unlike any model of formal set theory, since the domain of a model is a collection.

**Type theory**  Another solution, which I am much less familiar with, is using type theory to limit collection principles.  Are there many modern set theorists who favor this resolution?  Or has the proper class idea overriden this solution?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you think standard texts in set theory do not "resolve" Russell's paradox. It seems to me that most introductory set theory texts contain clear explanations of why Russell's paradox is not an issue when we work in first-order ZFC.

Comment: I'm also confused by "if sets were meant to formalize the general notion of a "collection", then a true/Platonic set theory should have no "models" at all". A model is just that, a model. There's no reason to expect a model of a first-order set theory to contain all collections, any more than we would expect a countable model of the first-order theory of the real field to contain every real number.

Comment: Classes aren't "arbitrary" collections; they can't have classes as elements.  And thus no problem for Russell.  I'm a novice, but I really don't see Russell's paradox as saying anything deeper for modern set theory than "don't try to adopt the axiom schema of naive comprehension".

Comment: @NateEldredge I never said classes are arbitrary collections.  I just said they were collections.

Comment: @AlexKruckman My experience is different.  I would agree that most texts "avoid" the paradox, by limiting the comprehension axioms, but that undercuts the purpose of sets (as a formalization of arbitrary collections).  It also introduces extra layers of complexity (by introducing "classes" as collections that are too large to be sets).

Comment: Are you saying that from some philosophical perspective, we really "need" a set-like theory that does include naive comprehension, and that standard set theory is unsatisfactory because it doesn't?  I would guess that current set theorists would simply disagree with you.

Comment: @NateEldredge I've tried to clarify my question.  Feel free to ask additional questions, if that doesn't clear up what you are asking about.

Comment: I think the answer you get will depend on the kind of mathematician you ask. For me, as a category theorist, I think of set theory as formalising _small_ collections. And perhaps set theorists would say set theory formalises inductive/well-founded constructions.

Comment: @ZhenLin My impression of category theory (from the few texts I've read) is that it usually assumes some sort of axiom of universes, where any given universe is contained in a larger universe.  So there are sets in universe 0, then bigger sets in universe 1, etc...  Would you agree with that?  If not, please clarify.  If so, that's really just (normal) set theory with (lots of) strongly inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: @AlexKruckman To answer your question about my comment on models, consider the following question: Could any model of set theory actually be what we would consider the "true universe" of set theory? (The answer is no, the domain of a model is a set.)  By the way, it's not that I would necessarily want a model to contain all collections---its that I would want a model to actually 'model' the thing it is supposed to 'model'.

Comment: Assuming a proper class of strongly inaccessible cardinals doesn’t really change my perspective. It just creates a tower of smallness notions.

Comment: @ZhenLin So you don't take it as given that any category you ever work with lives inside some (small) universe?

Comment: It depends on what I am doing. If complicated constructions are not required I could work with categories that have a proper class of objects and morphisms. Sometimes complicated constructions are needed but I only need to consider small categories, or at worst essentially small categories. It isn’t always necessary to assume a universe.

Comment: @ZhenLin It sounds like, yes, when push comes to shove, you allow that some categories are not inside universes.  If so, how do you formalize "proper classes"?

Comment: Russell's Paradox says that the notion of an arbitrary collection is nonsense.  So sets can't formalize arbitrary collections; that would be formalizing nonsense.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Russell's paradox certain says that the notion of "the collection of all collections" is nonsense.  But I don't see how it undercuts the idea of an "arbitrary collection".  Do you have a reference to back up that stronger claim?

Comment: And for those downvoting, I would appreciate comments letting me know why you are downvoting.  I've tried to clarify the question quite a bit.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I (try to) work with NBG if I use proper classes. (But I don’t try very hard – I just remember to avoid the obvious pitfalls like trying to form a collection of proper classes; so it’s possible I accidentally stray into MK territory sometimes.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks!  Do you then view proper classes as something fundamentally different than sets?  (If so, what makes them fundamentally different?)  Or do you secretly view NBG as contained in MK, which is contained in a version of ZFC with universes?

Comment: I think of proper classes (= large collections) as being different from sets (= small collections), yes. I am aware that there is a (very useful) perspective that sees the NBG universe contained in the MK universe and the MK universe contained in, say, the universe of Mac Lane set theory with one Grothendieck universe. At the same time I am aware that axioms about what goes on high up in the cumulative hierarchy can imply things about arithmetic so I am wary of believing that this picture is “reality”. I suppose I’m not a Platonist.

Comment: @ZhenLin Aren't you a Platonist in this thing? Apparently you believe there is a way to separate collections into two types---one large and one small---even though that perspective is not *a priori* forced upon you.

Comment: So with your edits, I think I'm unclear as to what exactly you mean when you speak of  "arbitrary collections".  Evidently there are certain properties that you think a theory of "arbitrary collections" ought to have, and which standard set theory doesn't have, but it's not clear to me what they are.  It sounds, for instance, like you want there to be a "collection of all collections", but do you also think that the theory of collections ought to include comprehension?  If yes, why is it reasonable to "want" an inconsistent theory?  If no, then what if anything do you want in its place?

Comment: I don’t actually believe there are small collections and large collections, though. For one thing, I permit myself to change what I mean by small; for another, when I am feeling Platonistic my view would be that every collection is small in some context. I think I am a formalist, in practice.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but one possible explanation is that some of the question gives the impression of attacking straw men.  For instance, "we are never told why we can't collect classes into bigger classes".  I think many people would say there are perfectly clear reasons why you can't; e.g., if you think of classes as "syntactic sugar" for formulas, then you can't have a class of classes because classes (i.e. formulas) are simply not objects in set theory's universe of discourse.  The tone seems needlessly antagonistic, as if you're accusing set theorists of some sort of deceit.

Comment: To add to Nate Eldredge's last point, the question could be improved by quoting specific language where some set theorists put forward the picture you're suggesting.

Comment: I am far from well acquainted with philosophy, hence just a comment, but to reply tk your final question, of what sets in modern set theory formalize: in my eyes, the answer is essentially that they aim to capture the *iterative construction of sets*. We start with the empty set. Then we consider sets built out of it, and then sets built out of what we have so far, and so on. Rodrigo's answer essentially discusses  how we view this conception as being open-ended, hence without letting us consider the totality of all sets

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm sorry if the tone came across as antogonistic.  I was writing it with a smile on my face, but I'll try to edit.  I'll also try to adress the "syntactic sugar" comment (which is only one way to view classes, btw), Sam's comment, and Matt's comment.

Comment: @Wojowu I would agree, but would modify that to say: set theory aims to capture the *iterative construction of sets* through any *potentially plausible construction*.  This allows reasoning about strongly inaccessible cardinals, for instance.  But, as per Rodrigo's answer, I think there are some serious issues with reasoning about the "true" $V$ as if it were a completed object.  I'd love to hear from set theorists on that front.

Comment: You wrote: "Consider the following question: Could any model of set theory actually be what we would consider the "true universe" of set theory?" Of course not - but that's not the point of models of set theory. The point of models of set theory is to provide set-sized objects that we can manipulate to do meta-mathematics about the theory.

Comment: You wrote "I would want a model to actually 'model' the thing it is supposed to 'model'". To be tautological: models of ZFC are indeed models of ZFC, which is what they're supposed to model. It seems bizarre to take issue with the models here, when your actual concern is with the theory: Does ZFC *axiomatize* what it's supposed to *axiomatize*?

Comment: All that said, I've changed my downvote to an upvote, because I think the most recent revision of the question is actually an interesting philosophical question about the role of proper classes in set theory. It seems to me almost completely unrelated to the original version of the question!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks! I think you are right that "Does ZFC axiomatize what it's supposed to axiomatize?" is a good rephrasing of my concern.  Perhaps "Can any first order theory appropriately axiomatize the naive notion of collection, in light of Russell's paradox?" would be even more precise.  My comments about models were meant to be evidence towards a negative answer to these questions, but never as evidence against model theory itself! Note: There appear to be no such issues with respect to arithmetic.  The models of, say, Peano arithmetic, include what we would consider "true" arithmetic.

Comment: Note #2: Nor were my comments meant to be evidence against set theory, or ZFC in particular.  They were just meant to raise questions about how to interpret ZFC, proper classes, etc... from a meta-theoretic/philosophical perspective.

Comment: " It seems to me almost completely unrelated to the original version of the question!"  Ah, the joys of communication over the internet.

Comment: Possible partial duplicate, in light of the new/correct question interpretation? I think Joel's answer in particular is relevant. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45037/should-there-be-a-true-model-of-set-theory?rq=1

Comment: The solution I am naïvely familiar with — to call any kind of "set" a "class" instead of a set in case it created paradoxes — strikes me as being amazingly simple compared to the depth and subtlety of Russell's Paradox. **Too simple**, in fact. It didn't even require analyzing which kinds of situations lead to Russell's-type paradoxes!  What we really want is to find a resolution of the paradox that *includes* everything that *ought* to be a set and *excludes* everything that ought not to be one. Is the standard resolution the optimal one?

Answer (score 12):

Let me begin quoting W. Tait (lectures on proof theory, pages 4 and 5):

> I believe that what further has to be understood, in order to make
> sense of these 'paradoxes' is that the notion of a transfinite number or, equivalently,
> of a set of transfinite numbers is an essentially **open-ended** notion:
> no matter what principles we introduce to construct sets of numbers, providing
> only that these principles are well-defined, we should be able to admit all
> numbers obtained by these principles as forming a set, and then proceed on
> to construct new numbers. So $\Omega$ cannot be regarded as a well-defined extension:
> **we can only reason about it intensionally**, in terms of those principles
> for constructing numbers that we have already admitted, leaving open in our reasoning the possibility - in fact, the necessity - of always new principles for
> constructing numbers. When this is not understood and $\Omega$
> is counted as a
> domain in the sense of a well-defined extension, then the so-called paradoxes
> force on us a partitioning of well-defined extensions into two categories: sets
> and proper classes; and the only explanation of why such an extension should
> be a proper class rather than a set would seem to be simply that the assumption
> that it is a set leads to contradiction. The paradoxes deserve the name
> 'paradox' on this view because it offers no explanation of why there should
> be this dichotomy of well-defined extensions.

Emphases are mine ($\Omega$ is a reference to "the greatest ordinal"). So, one proposed rough sketch of an answer in the direction given by Tait (of course, there are many other directions in philosophy) is this:

- The subject matter of set theory is open-ended, therefore set theory must be about an intension, the concept of set, not about a well-defined extension. This intension is open-ended (it is hard to make sense of the oxymoron "open-ended well-defined extension"), and it is the unifying criterion behind the plurality of set theoretical practices. The contemporary criterion can be more or less approximated by $ZFC$, but there can be no definite final stage on the progressive conceptual unification of the set-theoretical practices, as there is a neccessary open-endedness (incompleteness) in this intension.

There are many things to address here, but I will not try to pursue them, not even in outline, as this would lead us to a more hardcore philosophical activity.
As a final remark, there are similar arguments in the history of philosophy which were given many years before Russell. One of the most relevant is Plato's third man argument, in *Parmenides*.

SPECULATIVE ADDENDA:

I think the question "should there be a dichotomy of well-defined extensions and how can we deal with it?", a natural outcome of this discussion, is very relevant for the foundations of set theory, and there are many hints about this in traditional philosophy, say, from Plato to Hegel. I think the answer is no, and I agree with Tait's direction. (A small digression: "Platonism", as the term appears in the original question, has probably a very weak connection to Plato.  Plato is very subtle, he wrote dialogues, not theoretical treatises in philosophy, in which the dramatic elements interact with the philosophical elements, probably because he sees philosophy as the kind of argumentative activity he shows in the dialogues, not as a body of theory. See W. Tait, Truth an Proof: The Platonism of Mathematics. Anyway, I think, along with Tait, that the man deserves a better fate.)

I will not dare to say much more about our questions here, but I would like to remark on the idea that there can be no final conceptual unification, for any unification is synthetic, that is, made on the basis of a new conceptual synthesis which, as "new", cannot be among those very things now unified. If reason operates this way, progressively unifying its previous practices through conceptual synthesis, open-endendness is its fate, and I believe mathematics is the primary example of this.

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  I really like your rephrased question "should there be a dichotomy...".

Comment: That said, it seems to me that most mathematicians don't follow the advice of only reasoning about $\Omega$ intensionally.  Rather, ${\rm Ord}$ is treated as an object that one can reason about (perhaps only in the meta-theory, but still a concrete object), create models of, etc...  It's like we mathematicians want to have our cake, and eat it too.

Comment: Thanks, I have given just a rough sketch of the beginning of an answer. Many things must be addressed. But I believe those things can be at least partially addressed. I also believe that the alternative view of set theory as being about an extramathematical model or a collection of extramathematical models really introduces the dichotomy, (and alienates mathematical truth from its practice, making mathematics somewhat speculative or based on some private intellectual intuition which is much more mysterious than the mathematical practice that it presumably explains.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm definitely not an expert in set theory, but Russel's paradox has long since been dealt with by making the class–set distinction.

$V$ is the *class* of all *sets*, not the class of all classes or the set of all sets, and this is really the whole shebang. We aren't allowed to collect 'all collections of the same nature' (sets or classes) into a collection of that same nature (one big set or class) on pain of paradox, but we can collect all collections of a certain nature (sets) into a new, bigger type of collection with a different nature (a class).

We can even continue this hierarchy with 'hyperclasses' that are allowed to hold all classes but not other hyperclasses, etc, as explained in the answer to [An axiom for collecting proper classes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292350/an-axiom-for-collecting-proper-classes) by [Joel Hamkins](https://mathoverflow.net/a/292433) (and Andreas Blass/Kameryn Williams in the comments on Joel's answer).

In essence we can allow for a fundamentally 'bigger' type of collection, which can then hold all collections of a smaller type, but this new bigger type of collection will still never be able to collect up all collections of its own type —  we would have to once again step higher up the 'collection hierarchy', at which point we would run into the same situation again.

Comment: Alec, I hope that the edit to my question clarifies what I was asking.  Your answer seems to suggest that sets are no longer thought of (by set theorists) as formalizations of arbitrary collections, but rather as formalizations of small collections, among a chain of different types.  But isn't that chain of types just another version of set theory (perhaps with larger cardinals)?  Couldn't your so-called classes just be the sets past the first inaccessible cardinal?  Or, from another angle, what is it (fundamentally) that distinguishes a class from a set?--only the language?

Comment: @PaceNielsen It is true that from a consistency strength point of view, adding classes adds less consistency strength than even a single inaccessible cardinal, and so the classes of MK class theory (for example) can be viewed as the sets of a universe of ZFC+there is an inaccessible cardinal. It does seem that modern category theorists, at least, view sets as formalizing 'small' collections since this is exactly the terminology they use. (a category is small if all its homs form a set, locally small if each individual hom is a set, etc.)

Comment: @PaceNielsen I'm not sure about set theorists, good question. (although it doesn't really match the title of the question or the main body question from before anymore, which is what I was addressing).

Comment: I think I now understand some of the confusion.  Some readers took "Russell's paradox" as the formal statement that ZFC+Comprehension is inconsistent.  I understand Russell's paradox as a philosophical problem with naive set theory.  I'll add a comment to the question.

Comment: Is there a type of collection corresponding to every ordinal number? Such that a ω-collection can contain sets, classes, hyperclasses, hyperhyperclasses, hyperhyperhyperclasses, ... but not ω-collections. And a ω+1-collection may also contain ω-collections. And a 2ω-collection may contain all ω+n-collections for all natural numbers n, and so on.

Comment: @user253751 This sort of unbounded hierarchy of classes can be axiomatized using universes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe

Answer (score 0):

Russell's paradox depends on the local admissibility of universal exclusion, i.e. the "all and only" quantifier. Consider the difference between:

1. $\forall a\exists X((a \notin a) \implies (a \notin X))$
2. $\forall a \exists X((a \in X) \implies (a \notin a))$.

To get the Russell set, you have to merge (1) and (2) by composing the conditional arrow into the biconditional arrow, which is where the "and only" part of the universal exclusifier comes in.

The "upshot" is that you can deny (2) while retaining (1): you can say that there is some set that happens to have all noncircular elements to its name. However, if these are the only elements that set contains, then Russell's paradox arises, so we would have to say that if there is a set with all noncircular sets as elements, this set still is an element of itself *on the side*. This whole set does not have its elements just because they've been intensionally carved out as such, but either the whole set is "manually" self-inserted, or it satisfies a disjunctive property like, "All elements of $X$ are either noncircular or are $X$ itself."

Note, then, that there are set theories with universal sets, e.g. Quine's parafounded world, or Weber's paraconsistent $\aleph_\text{ORD}$. At least in the consistency-friendly such cases, if there is a universal set, then the axiom scheme of separation has to fail for this set, the powerset axiom to boot: for a truly universal set, there is no difference between its elements and its subsets, or the concept of it having subsets is not well-thought, so there are no separable subsets or separate sets of subsets in play, here.

Given phenomena like the conflict between zero sharp and the constructible universe, or the Kunen inconsistency, it is possible to reformulate most or perhaps all axioms as dependent in the sense that they "run out" at some point in the cumulative hierarchy. For example, you can compromise on [replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wholeness_axiom), [foundation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0814), or usually general choice, to work around the Kunen inconsistency (Corazza's approach gives us Reinhardt cardinals below a certain iterate of the embedding function; antifoundation worlds have n.e.e.'s involving their parafounded fragments but can retain the Kunen wall for their well-founded fragments). These phenomena then support what we might call "deflection arguments," which *contrast* a universal set with relatively infinite sets and lend themselves to an *anticlass principle:* "If a set contains all of a certain kind of element, then it contains all elements of all kinds whatsoever." E.g., if there is a set of all ordinals, there is yet no set of all ***and only*** ordinals, but this set has to have all the cardinals in it, too, etc.

Yet another solution (from the separation-minus vantage, but comporting more strictly with the axiom of foundation) would be to invoke ***couniversal*** sets. The pure example would be $$\exists X \forall ab((a \neq X) \iff (a \in X)).$$

The propriety of calling these "couniversal" is that they can be styled "sets of all *other* sets." In a world with a universal set *simpliciter*, then the deviant consequence obtains wherein the couniversal $X$ contains its superior as an element, which also contains $X$ in turn, so $X$ ends up being cofounded. So to avoid this, one would have to go to a world where there's a couniversal set without a universal set above it. In this event, $X$ is the set of all *elements*, not all sets (since $X$ itself is not, in that world, an element of any set, not even itself).

So then a couniversally noncircular set would be "the set of all other noncircular sets," which indicates its own noncircularity.

All these solutions end up requiring a stronger distinction between extensional and intensional elementhood parameters. Cantor infamously mistook definability for orderability, and in fact per the natural language in use at the time, Cantor's system involved a partial collapse of the extension-intension distinction into the cardinal-ordinal one. We "know better," though, so we can talk about an elementhood parameter that is "manually extensional" rather than a matter of elements satisfying intensions. (I wish I could find it again, but I read an essay in which they explicitly brought up a difference between "is an extensional element of" and "is an intensional element of," which I saw as a way to expand on [double-extension set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_extension_set_theory), which itself involves a relatively novel attempt to deal with Russell's paradox.)

Comment: In the first paragraph don't you have the quantifiers the wrong way round? Shouldn't $\forall a\exists X$ be $\exists X\forall a$?

Comment: @bof apologies, I am still a novice when it comes to a lot of the relevant notation. I've seen phrases like "prenex normal form" and all, but I have a hard time tracking when these things come into play (or why they're in play at all).