# Is there some absoluteness between the Boolean valued universe $V^{B}$ and $V$?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

It is well known that if $\phi$ is a $\Delta_{1}$-formula and $x_{1},..,x_{n}$ in $V$ and $V[G]$ is a forcing extension, then $V\models\phi(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ if and only if $V[G]\models\phi(x_{1},...,x_{n})$. In other words, we say that $\Delta_{1}$ formulas are absolute for forcing extensions. More generally, if $\phi$ is $\Sigma_{1}$, and $V\models\phi(x_{1},...,x_{n})$, then $V[G]\models\phi(x_{1},...,x_{n})$. I am wondering about what kind of absoluteness theorems hold between $V^{B}$ and $V$. Perhaps, there are absoluteness theorems where the formulas in $V^{B}$ are slightly different than the formulas in $V$.  Let me be more specific about what I mean.

Let $B$ be a complete Boolean algebra and let $V^{B}$ be the corresponding $B$-valued set theoretic universe. Suppose $\dot{X}\in V^{B}$. Let $\Gamma^{*}(\dot{X})=\{\dot{x}\in V^{B}:\|\dot{x}\in\dot{X}\|=1\}$. Let $\simeq$ be the equivalence relation on $\Gamma^{*}(\dot{X})$ where $\dot{x}\simeq\dot{y}$ iff $\|\dot{x}=\dot{y}\|=1$. Let $\Gamma(\dot{X})=\Gamma^{*}(\dot{X})/\simeq$.

Suppose that $n_{1},...,n_{r}$ are natural numbers and $V^{B}\models\dot{R}_{1}\subseteq\dot{X}^{n_{1}},...,\dot{R}_{k}\subseteq\dot{X}^{n_{r}}$.
Let $X=\Gamma(\dot{X})$. If $1\leq i\leq r$, then let $R_{i}$ be the $n_{i}$-ary relation on $X$ where $([x_{1}],...,[x_{r}])\in R_{i}$ if and only if $V^{B}\models (x_{1},...,x_{n_{i}})\in\dot{R}_{i}$.

Then for which n-th order formulas $\Phi$ do we have
$V^{B}\models((\dot{X},\dot{R}_{1},...,\dot{R}_{r})\models\Phi(\dot{a}_{1},...,\dot{a}_{r}))$ implies $(X,R_{1},...,R_{n})\models\Phi$ whenever $V^{B}\models\dot{a}_{1},...,\dot{a}_{r}\in\dot{X}$?

If $\Phi$ is a first order formula, then the answer to this question is fairly clear:

The structure $(X,R_{1},...,R_{r})$ is a Boolean product of the structures $(\dot{X},\dot{R}_{1},...,\dot{R}_{r})/U$ where $U$ ranges over the ultrafilters on $B$. However, Horn formulas are preserved under most Boolean products [see 1] including the Boolean products that one obtains from forcing. In particular, if $\Phi$ is a Horn formula, then $V^{B}\models((\dot{X},\dot{R}_{1},...,\dot{R}_{r})\models\Phi(\dot{a}_{1},...,\dot{a}_{r}))$ implies $(X,R_{1},...,R_{n})\models\Phi([\dot{a}_{1}],...,[\dot{a}_{n}])$ whenever $V^{B}\models\dot{a}_{1},...,\dot{a}_{r}\in\dot{X}$.

Furthermore, the Feferman-Vaught theorem also holds for most Boolean products [see 1], so the truth value of any formula in the structure $(X,R_{1},...,R_{n})$ is determined by the Boolean truth value of formulas in $(\dot{X},\dot{R}_{1},...,\dot{R}_{n})$.

However, it is not clear which higher order formulas are preserved by going between $V$ and $V^{B}$. I however must mention that some higher order sentences are preserved when one goes from $V^{B}$ to $V$. For example, it is a well known fact about iterated forcing that if $V^{B}\models``\dot{C}\,\textrm{is a complete Boolean algebra}"$, then $V\models``\Gamma(\dot{C})\,\textrm{is a complete Boolean algebra}"$. Perhaps this result can be generalize to a large class of first order formulas that contains the second order formula stating that the object is a complete Boolean algebra.

I would also appreciate it if someone supplied references for such absoluteness results. I am currently just interested in such absoluteness results between $V^{B}$ and $V$ and I am not as much interested right now in the corresponding absoluteness between $V^{B}/U$ and $V$ where $U$ is an ultrafilter.

[1](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1979-248-02/S0002-9947-1979-0522263-8/). [Sheaf constructions and their elementary properties](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1979-248-02/S0002-9947-1979-0522263-8/). Stanley Burris and Heinrich Werner. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 248 (1979), 269-309.

Comment: I suspect you may be interested in [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/32757/6085). In my answer there I give some references on generic absoluteness through the projective hierarchy. Joel's gives examples of a different nature.

Comment: I deleted this question earlier, but then I undeleted the question since now that I think of it a little more, it appears to be an interesting question, but I am in the process of editing this question to make it better.

Comment: I have edited this question. Now it should be much more answerable and clear what I am looking for.

Comment: Some first remark, $\check x$ is a *name* for an object in $V[G]$ which is the canonical name for the object $x$ from $V$, and moreover $\check x^G=x$. So you can just write $V\models\phi(x)\iff V[G]\models\phi(x)$. If you want to put emphasis on generic objects, then $\phi(\dot x^G)$ is preferable.